# The IOError when I use the Requests library in python

Tags: python, httprequest, gevent, python-requests, ioerror

when I use the Requests library, use its `async.map(reqs, size)` method, when the `reqs` is bit, following error occurs:

```
 IOError: zipimport: can not open file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gevent-0.13.6-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg
```

but the requests list is small,then no problem ,can anyone help me ?

The code is below:

```
from requests import async
from time import time
import numpy as np


#urls list
urls = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=str)
#urls = urls[:10]
cnt = 100

#main method
results = []
reqs=[]
def main():
   for i in range(cnt):
       start = time()
       for u in urls:
           reqs.append(async.get(u)) 
       stop = time()
       #print 'cicle %s = %s' %(i, stop-start)
       #results.append(stop-start)
   print len(reqs)
   async.map(reqs, size=100)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   begin = time()
   main()
   end = time()
   print end-begin
```

It works fine when `cnt = 10`, but errors out when trying with `cnt = 100`.

Comment: Could you please try setting `cnt` to 100 and changing the `async.map(reqs, size=100)` call to `async.map(reqs, size=5)` and see if that works?

Comment: Thank for your answer, but the problem also occurred, and I use the command : sudo python myxxxx.py .so the permission is also not the problem .